# Preg-Match-All - Synonym File

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am writing a php script that will parse through a file, (synonyms.dat), and coordinate a list of synonyms with their parent word, for about 150k words.

Example from file:

```
1|2
(adj)|one|i|ane|cardinal 
(noun)|one|I|ace|single|unity|digit|figure
1-dodecanol|1
(noun)|lauryl alcohol|alcohol
1-hitter|1
(noun)|one-hitter|baseball|baseball game|ball
10|2
(adj)|ten|x|cardinal 
(noun)|ten|X|tenner|decade|large integer
100|2
(adj)|hundred|a hundred|one hundred|c|cardinal 
(noun)|hundred|C|century|one C|centred|large integer
1000|2
(adj)|thousand|a thousand|one thousand|m|k|cardinal 
(noun)|thousand|one thousand|M|K|chiliad|G|grand|thou|yard|large integer
**10000|1
(noun)|ten thousand|myriad|large**
```

In the example above I want to link ten thousand, myriad, large to the word 1000.

I have tried various method of reading the .dat file into memory using file_get_contents and then exploding the file at \n, and using various array search techniques to find the 'parent' word and it's synonyms.  However, this is extremely slow, and more often then not crashes my web server.

I believe what I need to do is use preg_match_all to explode the string, and then just iterate over the string, inserting into my database where appropriate.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($page);
preg_match_all("/([^\s]+)\|[0-9].*/",$contents,$out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

This matches each

```
1|2

1-dodecanol|1

1-hitter|1
```

But I don't know how to link the fields in between each match, IE the synonyms themselves.

This script is intended to be run once, to get all the information into my database appropriately. For those interested, I have a database 'synonym_index' which holds a unique id of each word, as well as the word.  Then another table 'synonym_listing' which contains a 'word_id' column and a 'synomym_id' column where each column is a foreign key to synonym_index.  There can be multiple synonym_id's to each word_id.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split each line into fields. (Or, depending on the precise format of the input, [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) might be a better choice.)

Illustrative example, which will almost certainly need adjustment for your specific use case and data format:

```
$infile = fopen('synonyms.dat', 'r');
while (!feof($infile)) {
    $line = rtrim(fgets($infile), "\r\n");
    if ( $line === '' ) {
        continue;
    }

    // Line follows the format HEAD_WORD|NUMBER_OF_SYNONYM_LINES
    list($headWord, $n) = explode('|', $line);
    $synonyms = array();

    // For each synonym line...
    while ( $n-- ) {
        $line = rtrim(fgets($infile), "\r\n");
        $fields = explode('|', $line);
        $partOfSpeech = substr(array_shift($fields), 1, -1);
        $synonyms[$partOfSpeech] = $fields;
    }

    // Now here, when $headWord is '**10000', $synonyms should be array(
    //     'noun' => array('ten thousand', 'myriad', 'large**')
    // )
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I was looking for.  Contrariety to your suggestion that changes will be required, with the exception of some variable names, everything worked as it should.  Much better solution than my original, and the inclusion of the $partofSpeech variable is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, for this type of functionality you have databases with tables and indices. 
PHP is to serve a request/response, not to read a big file into memory. I advise you to put the data in a database. That will be much faster - and it is made for it.

Comment: The intention is the run this script one time, correctly and save the data into a database which I have created, I will update the question to reflect my database requirements. Apologies, I didn't think it was necessary in this question.

Comment: Apologies accepted. :-) Good solution provided by PleaseStand. I would have advised to use file, which returns an array of lines. I think that is always very handy.